# Comment rest of file in C#

Tags: c#, comments

In some languages, like Scheme, there's a way to comment out the rest of a file. Is there a way of doing this in C# without putting */ at the end of the file and /* where the comment begins? I'm just curious.

Comment: You can only use block comments (`/* blah */`) or rest-of-line comments (`// blah`)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Though if you want a quick way to do it with Visual Studio shortcuts, you can press `CTRL+SHIFT+END` (to highlight everything after your current caret position) then `CTRL+K, CTRL+C` (to comment it out).

Comment: The problem with that is that you would end up commenting out any block closings (`}`), which is also why a "comment to end" style would not be feasible.

Comment: @gmiley Yeah. That makes sense. I was working with a file that had somewhat of an alternate implementation of the entire namespace, so the closing blocks needed to go as well, but this is super rare case, so I get why C# sharp hasn't implemented it.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no method of commenting-to-end in C#. You only have `//` and `/* ... */` available to you. Here is an example of why you would not ever want a comment-to-end style in C#...

Consider the following:

```
namespace TestNamespace
{
   public class TestClass
   {
      public void DoSomething()
      {
         // Here is a comment-to-end-of-line.

      }
      /* The entire DoSomethinElse member is commented out...
      public void DoSomethingElse() 
      { 

      }
      */
   }
}
```

The above shows how rest-of-line and block style comments work. Consider if you had a way to comment out the rest of a file, let's use `***` to indicate that the rest of the document should be commented out as an example.

```
namespace TestNamespace
{
   public class TestClass
   {
      public void DoSomething()
      {
         // Here is a comment-to-end-of-line.

      }
      *** The rest of the document should be commented out from here...
      public void DoSomethingElse() 
      { 

      }

   }
}
```

In the situation above, what you would end up doing is effectively this:

```
namespace TestNamespace
{
   public class TestClass
   {
      public void DoSomething()
      {
         // Here is a comment-to-end-of-line.

      }
      /* The rest of the document should be commented out from here...
      public void DoSomethingElse() 
      { 

      }
   }
}
       That includes all of the remaining block closings, which will cause compile errors.
      */
```

Without some way to tell the compiler to stop skipping lines, your code blocks will be unclosed and your code will not compile.